# Could not locate clojure/contrib/string__init.class or clojure/contrib/string.clj on classpath

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using a method from the contrib.string libraries but lein is having trouble finding the library.

In my project.clj I have `:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]` inside of `defproject` and then `(use '[clojure.string :only (join)]) (use '[clojure.contrib.string :only (as-str)])` inside of `src/file.clj`

Do I need to add another dependency to include contrib? I have found examples of 1.2, but there seems to have been a shift and the documentation is, well, lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monolithic contrib is long gone, it had been split into several modules when clojure 1.3.0 was released. Now `clojure.string` belongs to standard clojure library. There are no `as-str` function in that namespace, but given its name I assume that you need `str` function.

UPD: I searched for `as-str` function and found that it works in the same way as `str` do, but takes only name of keywords and symbols, ignoring namespace and ':' keyword prefix. I think now you can do it only by writing the same functionality by yourself (I also had to do the same in my recent code).

Answer (score 0):

the contrib.string is merged into clojure.string in clojure-1.4.0.